# iPhone X Kernel Panic Troubleshooting

Tags: iphone, kernel-panic

My iPhoneX keeps randomly restarting after upgrading to iOS 16.

I did a full factory reset natively using the phone and the problem persists. I then did a full factory restore using a mac by putting the phone into recovery mode, and it didnt resolve the issue!

I am now trying to troubleshoot what is causing it to restart and I tried to look into the kernel panic logs and the following is what I got:

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff021ab74fc): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from thermalmonitord
service returned not alive with context : is_alive_func returned unhealthy : current 73fffffffff, mask 67fffffffff, expected 67fffffffff.  SD: 1 BC: 1 RC: 0 BS: 0, Missing sensor(s): mic1 
service: backboardd, total successful checkins in 195 seconds: 19, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: SpringBoard, total successful checkins in 168 seconds: 17, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: mediaserverd, total successful checkins in 195 seconds: 18, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: logd, total successful checkins in 195 seconds: 19, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: thermalmonitord, no successful checkins in 195 seconds
service: runningboardd, total successful checkins in 195 seconds: 19, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: wifid, total successful checkins in 195 seconds: 19, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: configd, total successful checkins in 195 seconds: 18, last successful checkin: 0 seco
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x1
OS release type: User
OS version: 20E252
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 20:42:16 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.102.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8015
KernelCache UUID: 5E3826E4D8E3FE94830A61F88B96904A
Kernel UUID: 2F82D40E-2839-3B43-81ED-946F3EDCF364
Boot session UUID: BB8C756B-465D-4B5B-9A51-09A0BA66305F
iBoot version: iBoot-8422.100.650
secure boot?: YES
roots installed: 0
Paniclog version: 14
Kernel slide:      0x000000001aee0000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff021ee4000
mach_absolute_time: 0x1175a56fb
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x6441a9d7 0x00053f7d
  Sleep   : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x6441aa90 0x000d5ec5

Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffffdc06e58000 - 0xffffffe206e58000
  . VM    : 0xffffffdc06e58000 - 0xffffffdced4bc000
  . RO    : 0xffffffdced4bc000 - 0xffffffdd3a188000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffffdd3a188000 - 0xffffffde207ec000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffffde207ec000 - 0xffffffdf06e50000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffffdf06e50000 - 0xffffffdfed4b8000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffffdfed4b8000 - 0xffffffe0d3b20000
  . DATA  : 0xffffffe0d3b20000 - 0xffffffe206e58000
  Metadata: 0xffffffee57734000 - 0xffffffee58f34000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffee58f34000 - 0xffffffee59730000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

TPIDRx_ELy = {1: 0xffffffde21103e10  0: 0x0000000000000001  0ro: 0x000000016afff0e0 }
CORE 0: PC=0x00000001e82dc764, LR=0x00000001e82dc75c, FP=0x000000016b00a530
CORE 1 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 2: PC=0x00000001c646d99c, LR=0x00000001c646d984, FP=0x000000016d0ba240
CORE 3: PC=0x00000001abd0b35c, LR=0x000000019e65b958, FP=0x000000016b696070
CORE 4: PC=0xfffffff022104f44, LR=0xfffffff022104f44, FP=0xffffffe62e6abef0
CORE 5: PC=0xfffffff022104f44, LR=0xfffffff022104f44, FP=0xffffffe62ec7bef0
Compressor Info: 13% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 5% of segments limit (OK) with 1 swapfiles and OK swap space
Total cpu_usage: 115813791
Thread task pri cpu_usage
0xffffffde21103e10 watchdogd 97 14525
0xffffffde210ccfe8 backboardd 63 105326
0xffffffde214330e0 geod 37 14883
0xffffffde216e32d0 launchd 37 15467
0xffffffde20cc1870 kernel_task 0 5108030

Panicked task 0xffffffde1fe8b9f8: 203 pages, 4 threads: pid 57: watchdogd
Panicked thread: 0xffffffde21103e10, backtrace: 0xffffffe62e747130, tid: 1325
          lr: 0xfffffff0220d8c84  fp: 0xffffffe62e7471a0
          lr: 0xfffffff0221f3cc4  fp: 0xffffffe62e747210
          lr: 0xfffffff0221f2cd4  fp: 0xffffffe62e7472f0
          lr: 0xfffffff02209d5fc  fp: 0xffffffe62e747300
          lr: 0xfffffff0220d86cc  fp: 0xffffffe62e7476b0
          lr: 0xfffffff0226ffac8  fp: 0xffffffe62e7476d0
          lr: 0xfffffff021ab74fc  fp: 0xffffffe62e7476f0
          lr: 0xfffffff021ab6e88  fp: 0xffffffe62e747710
          lr: 0xfffffff021ab6054  fp: 0xffffffe62e747830
          lr: 0xfffffff022693920  fp: 0xffffffe62e7479d0
          lr: 0xfffffff0221c3d30  fp: 0xffffffe62e747af0
          lr: 0xfffffff0220dde9c  fp: 0xffffffe62e747b70
          lr: 0xfffffff0220b8668  fp: 0xffffffe62e747bd0
          lr: 0xfffffff0220cc4c8  fp: 0xffffffe62e747c80
          lr: 0xfffffff0220cc8c4  fp: 0xffffffe62e747d80
          lr: 0xfffffff0221e9e98  fp: 0xffffffe62e747e30
          lr: 0xfffffff0221f30f8  fp: 0xffffffe62e747f10
          lr: 0xfffffff02209d5fc  fp: 0xffffffe62e747f20
```

I ran [iDevice log analyser](https://github.com/waynebonc/iDeviceLogAnalyzer-public) and it said possible cause power button flex, charging flex but looks like thats not what the issue is.

What else can I consider based on these logs?

Additional Info:

The iPhone doesnt get hot for it to restart, and there is no pattern on restarting, it appears quite random!

Comment: What other evidence do you have to discount what iDevice Log Analyser is recommending?

Comment: @AndyGriffiths the main evidence is the correlation that it did not happen in previous iOS 15 and only when I upgraded to iOS 16, hardware dont get magically broken by a software update, right?

Comment: No, that's an assumption. Unfortunately you can't downgrade to test. I'd suggest a factory reset and if no joy then book a service appointment. You also need to get a handle on 'randomly restarting'. Is it after a certain time following a reboot? Is it while the device gets warm (I notice references to `thermalmonitord`) indicating a lot of background processing, as is common following an iOS upgrade? Is it when you run a certain application?

Comment: @AndyGriffiths I have done full factory reset using macbook as well, and unfortunately the issue persists. I dont have liberty to book a service appointment, hence I am troubleshooting myself. Also I noticed it does get little warm, I have no apps installed other then what the factory reset provides.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths also the restart seems to happen randomly within 2 mins from iphone restart while iphone is still cold to touch. I also activated low power mode and still the restart happens, so I am temporarily ruling out battery overheating issue, battery health is 86%